# How can I pass extended JVM options from Spring bootRun using Gradle?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm trying to enable different run profiles in build.gradle. One would be for "normal" run conditions and another one would be for local development. The local development should activate my "local" spring profile and also listen for debug on a specific port. This is what I have so far in my build.gradle:

```
    task localBootRun(dependsOn: bootRun) {
    bootRun {
        args = ["--spring.profiles.active=local"]
    }
}
```

And this works when I invoke the localBootRun task from gradle:

```
./gradlew localBootRun
```

What I can't figure out is how to pass extended JVM arguments necessary to listen for a debugger. Ordinarily, I would pass these on the JVM command line:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8005
```

But I can't figure out how to tell my localBootRun task to pass those as arguments to the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me in this particular scenario:

```
bootRun {
    args = ["--spring.profiles.active=local"]
    jvmArgs = ["-Xdebug", "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8005"]
}
```

Then, I invoke the task normally:

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

Seems to work great!

If you want a different or default bootRun task, there is a little more work:

```
def profileVal = project.hasProperty('profile') ? project.property('profile') : 'default'
bootRun {
    args = ["--spring.profiles.active=${profileVal}"]

    if (profileVal == "local") {
        jvmArgs = ["-Xdebug", "-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8005"]
    }
```

And then you can invoke it normally:

```
./gradlew bootRun
```

For a "default" run or invoke it with the profile:

```
./gradlew -Pprofile=local bootRun
```

For a "local" profile with debug.

There are probably better or different ways to do this, but this has worked for me.